# What is leaking rate?

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow

I am implementing an echo state network using TensorFlow and am studying the parameters, one of which is called "leaky". The documented definition is as follows:

> Float between 0 and 1. Leaking rate of the reservoir. If you pass 1,
> it's the special case the model does not have leaky integration.
> Default: 1.

I searched the internet but could not find a definition, in the context of neural networks and machine learning, as to what this parameter does, or what leaky integration is.

https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/ESN

Comment: Can you share a reference to the model.

Comment: @Peter Please see link in updated question

Comment: @Peter Please see link in updated question